# Strange behaviour executing query on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'll try to explain what happend to me without pasting every single piece of my code because it's a lot.

If I run this query alone it returns 6.0 (the expected behaviour)

```
select distancia_euclediana_para_imagenes(vector_cuadrante1,
                       vector_cuadrante2,
                       vector_cuadrante3,
                       vector_cuadrante4,
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)])
from imagen,pivotes 
where id=id_imagen and indice_pivote=2
```

and if I run this other query it returns 2 (again the expected behaviour)

```
with distancia_a_pivote(distancia) as
(select distancia_euclediana_para_imagenes(vector_cuadrante1,
                       vector_cuadrante2,
                       vector_cuadrante3,
                       vector_cuadrante4,
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)])
from imagen,pivotes 
where id=id_imagen and indice_pivote=2)
select id from imagen, indice, distancia_a_pivote d
where id=id_imagen  and
fqa[2]>= 6-1 and
fqa[2]<= d.distancia+1;
```

However, with this little change it stops working and returns nothing

```
with distancia_a_pivote(distancia) as
(select distancia_euclediana_para_imagenes(vector_cuadrante1,
                       vector_cuadrante2,
                       vector_cuadrante3,
                       vector_cuadrante4,
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)],
                       ARRAY[SQRT(8),SQRT(8)])
from imagen,pivotes 
where id=id_imagen and indice_pivote=2)
select id from imagen, indice, distancia_a_pivote d
where id=id_imagen  and
fqa[2]>= d.distancia-1 and
fqa[2]<= d.distancia+1;
```

I'll be grateful if you could help me because I have no idea what can cause this issue. Besides I've been coding in a TDD style, so I have tests to prove the right behaviour and I was pretty it was going to work

Thanks

Comment: What is `fqa[2]`? The integer 5 perhaps?

Comment: yes, do you have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that `fqa[2]` is the integer 5 and `d.distancia` is the *floating point* value 6.0. That means that you end up looking at this:

```
5 >= 6.0 - 1
```

That 6.0 probably isn't exact so `6.0 - 1` could come out a shade less than 5.0 and your comparison would fail. One solution is to add a little bit wiggle room to account for the usual floating point problems:

```
fqa[2] >= d.distancia - 1.00001 and
fqa[2] <= d.distancia + 1.00001
```

The 0.00001 is just an example, you'd need to look at your situation to see how much extra you should allow. Adding [`ceil` and `floor`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) calls might be another option as they would give you better control over the floating point to integer conversion.